# How to remove sabnzbdplus service?

Tags: services

I recently removed Sabnzbdplus from my ubuntu 18.04 install via the software centre but on startup I still get the message:

starting LSB:sabnzbd+ (and then a description of the program)

How do I get rid of the service running at startup? I don't think it's doing anything it's just for my piece of mind.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A method to find files is ...

```
sudo updatedb
locate sabnzbdplus
```

It will report any file still lingering with `sabnzbdplus` in the name.

Likely culprits ...

```
/etc/init.d/sabnzbdplus
sabnzbdplus.service
```

The 1st you can remove. The 2nd you can disable/mask/remove.

Comment: Thanks. Worked a treat!

Comment: cool! don't forget to accept if it is acceptable :)